# Play video on top of rest of site on button press

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, video, youtube

I'm designing a Bootstrap site with a video banner on the home page similar to [AirBnB](https://www.airbnb.com/). When I press the play button, I want to fade the site and play a YouTube video over the contents of the site. An example would be [KindlyCare](https://www.kindlycare.com/)'s play video button. When you press that play button the video loads in on top of the rest of the site. How do I tell the YouTube player to load over the site instead of embedded in the site?

**Edit** I'm using bootstrap

Comment: I suggest using something such as Bootstrap's Modal and HTML5 video with autoplay. Have you considered this?

Comment: I guess you can't open the youtube player whitout embedd your video on the site .... maybe what you really need is embed the video on some kind of modal with autoplay or fullscreen

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap, looks like Modal is the way to go, if someone posts an answer related to that ill accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a div that has a higher `z-index` than the rest of the document with either either CSS (`z-index: x;`) or jQuery (`$("element").css("z-index", "x")`) that is darkened and contains the youtube player, which should be in the form of an iframe or embed element. When the button is clicked (`$("element").on("click", ...)` or `$("element").click(...)`) then fade that darkened `div` in using `$("element").fadeIn()`.

If it is in the form of a script, make sure that the element that it is targeting (either the body or something else) is changed to the div that is over the webpage.

Comment: I forgot about z-index, you're right this is a good way to do it. However, I'm using bootstrap so I think I can just use a modal (see comment on question)

Comment: Ah, gotcha. That makes sense, I didn't realize you were using that.

Comment: Accepted this answer since nobody else posted one for bootstrap and I got it working